# Data modal dialog does not show up

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a button that will view the vehicles details when clicked. how ever, my data modal dialog does not show up. here is my codes..

```
<table class="table table-striped">  
                                          <tr>  
                                               <th width="40%">Plate Number</th>
                                               <th width="30%">Type</th>  
                                               <th width="30%">View</th>  
                                          </tr>  
                                          <?php  
                                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                                          {  
                                          ?>  
                                          <tr>  
                                               <td><?php echo $row["plateNo_vehicle"]; ?></td> 
                                               <td><?php echo $row["vehicle_Type"];?></td> 
                                               <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $row["id_vehicle"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                                          </tr>  
                                          <?php  
                                          }  
                                          ?>  
                                     </table>
```

this is the modal class and the script. the script supposed to contain ajax that supposed to view all the vehicle detail but i changed it just to pop up a data modal dialog only because the data modal wont show up at all.

```
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">  
       <div class="modal-content">  
            <div class="modal-header">  
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Vehicles Details</h4>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body" id="vehicle_detail">  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </div>
```

script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.view_data').click(function(){
        $('#dataModal').modal("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: check your browser's console and look for errors. What errors do you see?

Comment: @CodeGodie how do i check the browser's console?

Comment: common, right click on the webpage and click on inspect element, and than click on console tab

Comment: if youre using Chrome, right click and click "inspect", when the window opens, make sure "Console" is selected then refresh the page.

Comment: most likely jQuery or bootstrap JS is not installed correctly

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 it states that the modal is not a function

Comment: show the HTML code where your'e loading bootstrap JS and jQuery.

Comment: <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: is it this one that ure asking for?

Comment: it seems like youre loading jquery twice. First instance: `<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>` , second instance: `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/…` this may be causing conflicts. Stick with the latest.

Comment: @CodeGodie it worked! thanks! i just deleted the last one and it worked.

Comment: cool, ill add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're loading jQuery twice.

First instance: `<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Second instance: `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/…`

this may be causing conflicts. Stick with the latest version only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap you can just add:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataModal"
```

attributes in your button

Comment: i did as you said. the data modal show up, but for the script is does not works.